# Code gets stuck in loop (but loop itself doesn't keep going). C++ string

Tags: c++, c, string, loops, output

I am currently self-studying C++ with Schaum's outline book (which covers mostly C contents, or so I've been told, but whatever) and I have encountered some trouble with problem 9.8.
You are supposed to count the number of appearances of every different word in a given c++ string, for which I assumed each word was separated from the next one by a white space, a newline or a dot or coma (followed in these two last cases by another white space).
My code is the following:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{ string s;
  cout << "Enter text (enter \"$\" to stop input):\n";
  getline(cin,s,'$');
  string s2 = s, word;
  int ini = 0, last, count_word = 0;
  int count_1 = 0, count_2 = 0, count_3 = 0;
  cout << "\nThe words found in the text, with its frequencies, are the following:\n";
  for (ini; ini < s.length(); )
  {   // we look for the next word in the string (at the end of each iteration 
     // ini is incremented in a quantity previous_word.length()
    last = ini;
    cout << "1: " << ++count_1 << endl;
    while(true)
    { if (s[last] == ' ') break;
      if (s[last] == '\n') break;
      if (s[last] == ',') break;
      if (s[last] == '.') break;
      if (last > s.length()-1 ) break;
      ++last;
     cout << "2: " << ++count_2 << endl;
    }
    --last; // last gives the position within s of the last letter of the current word
    // now me create the word itself
    word = s.substr(ini,last-ini+1); //because last-ini is word.length()-1
    int found = s2.find(word);
    while( found != s2.length() ) // the loop goes at least once
      ++count_word;
      s2.erase(0,found+word.length()); // we erase the part of s2 where we have already looked
      found = s2.find(word);
      cout << "3: " << ++count_3 << endl;
    cout << "\t["<<word<<"]: " << count_word;
    ++last;
    s2 = s;
    s2.erase(0,ini + word.length()); // we do this so that in the next iteration we don't look for
                                     // the new word where we know it won't be.
    if (s[last] == ' ' || s[last] == '\n') ini = last + 1;
    if (s[last] == ',' || s[last] == '.') ini = last + 2;
    count_word = 0;
  }
}
```

When I ran the program nothing was sshown on screen, so I figured out that one of the loops must had been stuck (that is why I defined the variables count_1,2 and 3, to know if this was so).
However, after correctly counting the number of iterations for the fist word to be found, nothing else is printed and all I see is the command prompt (I mean the tiny white bar) and I cannot even stop the program by using ctrl z.

Comment: If you run the programmer under a debugger, you can hit "pause" when it is "stuck in a loop". That will tell you everything you need to know.

Comment: Your `while( found != s2.length() )` loop is missing braces, so it will only run the next line (`++count_word;`) in the loop, instead of all of the indented statements.  Since `++count_word` can never change the value of `found`, the loop will continue forever.

Comment: I have checked the absence of braces on the second while loop and it's fine. The problem still lies in the third loop though, but I cannot find it.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very complicated method for a very simple problem. You can just use a `stringstream` to extract each word seperated by a white space. You then just take the extracted word and increment the word counter using a `std::map<std::string, int>`.

My take on this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

int main() {
    std::map<std::string, int> word_to_count;
    std::string in;
    std::getline(std::cin, in);
    
    std::stringstream s(in);
    std::string temp_word;
    while (s >> temp_word) {
        word_to_count[temp_word]++; 
    }
    
    for (const auto& x : word_to_count) {
        std::cout << x.first << ": " << x.second << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

### input

```
hello world hello world test
```

### Output

```
hello: 2
test: 1
world: 2
```

Keep in mind this is just one of many possible solutions, so just take this as inspiration :).